# External Hard Drive not detected after reboot

Tags: 16.04

Whenever rebooting my computer it does not recognize my external hard drive until I Unplug it and then plug it back in. So, it is detecting it only after the unplug exercise. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the logs, beginning at the last reboot with `journalctl -b`. Is your external hard drive mentioned? What type of filesystem does your drive use?

Comment: Is your external drive always connected, when you boot, or do you want the system to look for it, but not complain, if the drive is not connected?