# USB external hard drive not detected on startup

Tags: boot, server, mount, hard-drive

Similar to a previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084629/external-hard-drive-not-detected-after-reboot), however that question seems to have gone cold.

I'm running a Ubuntu 19.04 server, with `plex` and `samba` installed.
Currently what happens on a reboot, is my external hard drive is not listed by
`fdisk -l`. I unplug and re-plug the drive in.

This also has the added affect of the device name changing.

- e.g. started as `/dev/sdf2`
- presently showing as `/dev/sda2`

Is there a way of having the drive still be detected on start up and keep the mapping persistent over reboots? Just as it is a little annoying having to reconnect the drive, and re-map it manually.

The drive is formatted as `NTFS` (my main PC is a Windows 10 PC, and the one that I access most stuff from)

Current commands used to mount the drive are:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda2 /media/storage
```

Where `/dev/sda` changes when the drive is re-connected.

Comment: For the mapping: reference it by its UUID instead of the device node. See `man mount` and look for the `-U, -uuid ` switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `blkid` to find the UUID of your device.

```
sudo blkid | grep ntfs
```

Then change your mount command into something like this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 -U 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000 /media/storage
```

just replace the `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000` part with your device's UUID.

Also, consider saving it to [fstab](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/pl/man5/fstab.5.html) instead of using mount command directly.